# which is the url for webhook between googleassitant and PHP

Tags: php, json, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I am reading request from DialogFlow ,storing it in database and need to send response back through webhook and php to google assitant.

Could anyone tell me which is the url to be speicified in $sending_url in PHP.
[image]

Thanks in advance
prashanth

Answer (score 1):

There is no sending URL. In the webhook model, you don't make an API call. Instead, something will call you, and you respond. This may be as easy as setting the header to JSON and printing out the response.